# Posting a form to an iframe and get back the content from iframe with javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I am working on a website in which i need get content from iframe. 
code is here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-lates…
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://glimmertech.org/IF222.htm" width="80%" height="600" id="frameDemo">       </iframe>

    <script>
    var myFrame = $('#frameDemo');

    myFrame.load(function()
    {
       var myjQueryObject = $('#frameDemo').contents().find('#newid'…
       alert(myjQueryObject[0].innerHTML);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't reach into an iFrame on a different domain. If there was a way it could be on the same domain (proxy server perhaps?) then you can use $.contents()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var myIframe = document.getElementById('frameDemo');
 var myObject = myIframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('newid');
 alert(myObject.innerHTML);
```

Comment: sorry, its not wrking, because iframe is from another domain